# HTML5 tag for definition something from unordered list

Tags: html, semantic-markup

I want to create a list of my skill, and when I click one of them, it shows something description from its list. What is the semantic tag for the 'something description from one of the lists' in HTML5?

Comment: Please visit the [help] to see what and [ask]. HINT: Post effort and CODE.

Comment: The first link on https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bsemantic-markup%5D+description looks promisng

Comment: Please no "bro" or "dude" it is [NOT appropropriate in English.](http://www.straitstimes.com/opinion/guys-please-stop-saying-bro-dude-and-mate)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that is it.

```
<dl>
    <dt>Heading</dt>
    <dd>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">listItem</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">listItem</a></li>
        </ul>
    </dd>
</dl>
```

Answer (score 1):

That sounds like a link.

```css
h2 {
  margin-top: 100vh;
  padding-top: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<h1>Skills</h1>

<ul>
  <li><a href="#examplea">Example A</a></li>
  <li><a href="#exampleb">Example B</a></li>
  <li><a href="#examplec">Example C</a></li>
  <li><a href="#exampled">Example D</a></li>
</ul>

<h2 id="examplea">Example A</h2>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus fermentum consectetur nibh, vel volutpat nulla varius a. Fusce auctor est id egestas imperdiet.</p>


<h2 id="exampleb">Example B</h2>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus fermentum consectetur nibh, vel volutpat nulla varius a. Fusce auctor est id egestas imperdiet.</p>


<h2 id="examplec">Example C</h2>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus fermentum consectetur nibh, vel volutpat nulla varius a. Fusce auctor est id egestas imperdiet.</p>


<h2 id="exampled">Example D</h2>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus fermentum consectetur nibh, vel volutpat nulla varius a. Fusce auctor est id egestas imperdiet.</p>
```

Comment: Almost, nice info. Thanks!